# UiTableViewCell is not displaying in Storybord

Tags: ios, uitableview

UiTableViewCell is not displaying in Storybord,
UiTableViewCell is not displaying in Storybord,UITableViewCell is not displaying in Storybord  can any one help me Thanks in advance

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
            return 1;
        }
    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return 50;
        }

    -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            return 100;
        }
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";
            ContactsCell *cell = (ContactsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[ContactsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }
               cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: cell.textlable.text is missing.. plz add

Comment: ok help me one thing if i click on a anycell it want to go to chatviewcontroller how can i do that

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 
    Chatviewcontroller * chatviewcontroller = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Chatviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatviewcontroller animated:YES];
}

Comment: thaq frd :) but when i click a cell i want to display the cell name in backbutton of nagivations in chat viewcontroller how can i do that ? plz help me

Comment: Add this line you didselectrowatindexpath method...            UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add your Cell Name" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain   target:nil  action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];

Comment: but i have each cell with different different names what i have to do then?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

Comment: plz go through some tutorial...may help you.. bcs your coding understanding is very lowww.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you wrote nothing to display in table

in cellforrow at indexpath add below line

```
cell.textlable.text=@"add something";
```

or replace your cellforrowatindexpath with below code

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";

        ContactsCell *cell = (ContactsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            cell = [[ContactsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }



           cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


 cell.textlable.text=@"add something";


        return cell;

}
```

Comment: cell is appearing but i given imageview n i given default image n labels in a cell but its not going to appear in cell y? :(

Comment: you didnt added anything to cell, did you tried my code

Comment: no i just drag n dropped a image n some labels in cell

Comment: then you have to add the the cell to tableview like a custom tableview

Comment: ya i taken a tableview n i added a cell to that n i given name as "contact cell" in that cell i added some elements like image n labels n i written the code as shown in above but i am not getting that image n label names

Answer (score 0):

Have you set **Delegate** and **DataSource** of you UITableView?

Using,

```
    [self.IByourTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.IByourTableView setDataSource:self];
```

Update #1: For answer comment(ie: Open ChatViewController),

for that use delegate method of **UITableView**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

var storyBoardName = "Main"
var storyBoard:UIStoryboard?

storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)

    var gotoViewController: UIViewController? = storyBoard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerIdentifier") as? UIViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(gotoViewController!, animated: true)

}
```

Note:Go to Story board and give Identifier to your ChatViewController

Comment: ya i have set but its not showing the image which i have given in a cell

Comment: ok help me one thing if i click on a anycell it want to go to chatviewcontroller how can i do that

Answer (score -1):

Do you know that you can't make UITableViewCell appear in storyboard by writing code? All the code you wrote will only display in the device.

You want UITableViewCell to appear in storyboard then you need to open storyboard and start adding and editing your uitableviewcell not by writing code.

Comment: ok help me one thing if i click on a anycell it want to go to chatviewcontroller how can i do that

Comment: This Delegate method take cares of that. You just need to add it into your code:
 
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
 if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        UIViewController *Main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Main animated:YES];
    }
}

Comment: thaq frd :) but when i click a cell i want to display the cell name in backbutton of nagivations in chat viewcontroller how can i do that ? plz help me @Anthony Tran